# Copying array in C v/s copying structure in C

Tags: arrays, structure, copying

Arrays and structures in C store data in memory which is contiguous. Then why is that C does not allow direct copying of arrays using "=" where as it is allowed for structure.
Example:

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int b[3];
b = a; // why is this not allowed. 

struct book b1, b2;
b1.page = 100;
b1.price = 10.0;

b2 = b1; // Why is this allowed
```

Comment: That's just how the language is defined. If you want to be able to copy an array by assignment, set it as the member of a struct.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question

You cannot directly write to an array, you can write only to the individual cells to an array.
You can use a for loop to initialize array b or memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b);

And with the structs the compiler does the memcpy for you.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you type : `b=a` , the compiler expects that you are assigning an array to b, but `a` is just a pointer to the location where the first element of the array is stored so there is a type mismatch.This is why `printf("%d",*a);` will print `1`.
And as for why structures can be assigned, it is because `b1` and `b2` in the above example are basically variables of the datatype `book` and variables can be assigned.When variables are assigned the contents are copied and they don't refer to the same memory location.This example might explain what i am saying more clearly:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct{int a;}num;
int main()
{
    num b,c;
    b.a = 10;
    c=b;
    b.a =11;
    printf("%d\n",(c.a));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `10`. This proves that `b` and `c` in this example do not point to the same memory.hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment requires that the type and therefore size of whatever is being assigned is known to the compiler.   So an assignment of form

```
 a = b;
```

requires that the types of `a` and `b` are both known to the compiler.   If the types are the same (e.g. both `a` and `b` are of type `int`) then the compiler can simply copy `b` into `a` by whatever instructions it deems are most efficient.     If the types are different, but an implicit promotion or type conversion is allowed, then the assignment is also possible after doing a promotion.    For example, if `a` is of type `long` and `b` is of type `short`, then `b` will be implicitly promoted to `long` and the result of that promotion stored in `a`.

This doesn't work for arrays, because the size of an array (calculated as the size of its elements multiplied by number of elements) is not necessarily known. One compilation unit (aka source file) may have a declaration (possibly by including a header file)

```
 extern int a[];
 extern int b[];

 void some_func()
 {
      a = b;
 }
```

which tells the compiler that `a` and `b` are arrays of `int`, but that they will be defined (which includes giving them a size) by another compilation unit.   Another compilation unit may then do;

```
 extern int a[];

 int a[] = {3,1,4,2,3};    /*  definition of a */
```

and a third compilation unit may similarly define `b` as an array of 27 elements.

Once the object files are linked into a single executable, the usages of `a` and `b` in all compilation units are associated, and all operations on them refer to the same definitions.

The problem with this comes about because the separate compilation model is a core feature of C.  So the compiler, when chewing on the first compilation unit above, has no information about the size of the arrays since it has no visibility of other compilation units, and is required to succeed or diagnose errors without referring to them.   Since there is no information about the number of elements in either array available to the first compilation unit, there is no way to work out how many elements to copy from one array to another.   The handling of this in C is that the assignment `a = b` is a diagnosable error in the function `some_func()`.

There are alternative approaches (and some other programming languages handle such cases differently) but they are generally associated with other trade-offs.

The considerations doesn't generally affect `struct` types, since their size is known at compile time.   So, if `a` and `b` are of the same `struct` type, the assignment `a = b` is possible - and can be implemented by (say) a call of `memcpy()`.

Note:  I am making some deliberate over-simplification in the explanation above, such as not considering the case of structs with flexible array members (from C99). Discussing  such cases would make the discussion above more complicated, without changing the core considerations.