# copying C-style arrays and structure

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct, variable-assignment

C++ does not allow copying of C-style arrays using `=`. But allows copying of structures using `=`, as in this link -> [Copying array in C v/s copying structure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296224/copying-array-in-c-v-s-copying-structure-in-c).It does not have any credible answers yet.
 But consider following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct user {
    int a[4];
    char c;
};

int main() {
    user a{{1,2,3,4}, 'a'}, b{{4,5,6,7}, 'b'};
    a = b;             //should have given any error or warning but nothing
    return 0;
}
```

Above code segment didn't gave any kind of errors and warnings, and just works fine. WHY?
Consider explaining both questions(this one and the one linked above).

Comment: Why should it give an error or warning? That's how `std::array` works. Looks correct for me

Comment: C++ also has `std::vector` which solves this problem.

Comment: this is c-style array not the std::array container of c++

Comment: @tadman idea is not to solve the problem, but to understand why is that problrm

Comment: @cdhowie i haven't used <array> header

Comment: Yes, but that's how `std::array` could basically be implemented. That's how `std::array` works behind the scenes.

Comment: @ThomasSablik you know when you try to copy c-style array, you get errors, but why not when i do the same as in the question, and I know c++ containers can easily sort this out

Comment: Because that's how C++ work. What answer do you expect? Your code is correct.

Comment: I'm actually a bit puzzled by this too: _"For non-union class types (class and struct), the operator performs member-wise copy assignment of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using built-in assignment for the scalars and copy assignment operator for class types."_ An array is not a class type, so is it a scalar? If that is the case then it uses "built-in assignment" which we've established arrays do not have.

Comment: @cdhowie I've pulled my answer, but I've always seen C++ deal with this properly *within `struct` or `class`* for reasons that I guess I can't articulate.

Comment: @tadman Same. I'm sure it's behavior defined by the standard, I just can't figure out where.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class `user` gets an [implicitly declared copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor) and [implicitly declared copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator).

The implicitly declared copy assignment operator copies the content from `b` to `a`.

Two passages from the standard that seems to apply:

[class.copy.ctor](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#14.1)

> if the member is an array, each element is direct-initialized with the corresponding subobject of x;

[class.copy.assign](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#12.2)

> if the subobject is an array, each element is assigned, in the manner appropriate to the element type;

Comment: I'm curious where it's declared that array members are copied. I can't find anything of the sort (on cppreference). Presumably the standard indicates this somewhere.

Comment: @cdhowie I'll have to dig in the standard. I'll give it a try on my lunch break. :-)

Comment: @cdhowie I found two passages that I think applies.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just checked, This things works in C as well without any warning or errors, I don't think the feature is C++ specific. It should be some carry forward feature possibly.

Comment: @beta_meme_beta That's entirely possible. I haven't been programming C for a very long time. The C standard would probably not talk about constructors though :-) Also, in C, all non-pointers are trivial so I'd expect a simple `memcpy` of the whole struct would work there.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the code should work fine. [arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Assignment) can't be assigned directly as a whole; but they can be assigned as data member by the [implicity-defined copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-defined_copy_assignment_operator), for non-union class type it performs member-wise copy assignment of the non-static data member, including the array member and its elements.

> Objects of array type cannot be modified as a whole: even though they
>   are lvalues (e.g. an address of array can be taken), they cannot
>   appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator:
>
> ```
> int a[3] = {1, 2, 3}, b[3] = {4, 5, 6};
> int (*p)[3] = &a; // okay: address of a can be taken
> a = b;            // error: a is an array
> struct { int c[3]; } s1, s2 = {3, 4, 5};
> s1 = s2; // okay: implicity-defined copy assignment operator
>          // can assign data members of array type
> ```